# H1 Logo in body not working correctly

Tags: php, html, css, tags

I am by far not an expert with PHP, and could really use some help creating my logo below into a H1. This is in my body section of the site:

```
<!--logo-->
<div class="logo" style="float:left;">

    <?php echo $html->link($html->image('rental_logo.png'),array('controller'=>'homes','action'=>'index'),array('escape'=>false)); ?>

</div>
<div class="logo" style="float: right; margin-right: 470px; padding-top: 40px;">
```

Here is what I tried to create the above logo into a H1 tag:

```
<h1>
    <a href="<?php echo $html->link($html->image('rental_logonew.png')?>" title="http://example.net/img/rental_logo.png"><br/>
    <img src="<?php (http://example.net/img/rental_logonew.png);>/images/rental_logo.png" alt="vacation rentals" title="logo"
</h1>
```

I am very inexperienced writing code. So, I know the above that I tried to enter is wrong. Should I also be altering my look.css file?

```
/* css */
#logo {
background: transparent url("http://example.net/img/rental_logo.png") no-repeat scroll 0%       0%;
 float: left;
/*width: 200px;*/
padding-bottom:10px;
text-indent: -3333px;
border: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#logo a {
display: block;
width: 280px; /* larger than actual image? */
height: 120px;
text-decoration: none;
border: 0;
}
```

I am attempting to add "rendered html" as requested. This may be incorrect, because I am unfamiliar with rendered html. I obtained the above codes from my header.ctp and look.css files.

```
($html->image('rental_logonew.png'),array('controller'=>'homes','action'=>'index'),array('escape'=>false)); ?>
```

Thanks for looking, and helping if you can.

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, not the PHP. It's irrelevant here.

Comment: You do realize that you're missing a closing `>` in `<img src="<?php (http://rentalology.net/img/rental_logonew.png);>/images/rental_logonew.png" alt="vacation rentals" title="logo"` <= right there, plus a missing `</a>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out jo8. The first box of code is what I see in my header.ctp. I am not sure how to view and provide it in any other way. I will try to look that up to provide it in this post.

Comment: So, did you read my comment, or was that irrelevant?

Comment: Thanks Fred for pointing the MIA tags out. Very relevant IMO. It will surely help!

Comment: You're welcome Jessica.

Comment: Jo8 or anyone that can help, I attempted to post the rendered html of my logo just now as requested, but I am not confident that I obtained it correctly. It is the first time I have heard of rendered html. If the html I have provided does not look rendered, would someone mind pointing me in the right direction please?

Comment: @Jessica Thats not rendered HTML as you already assumed. Rendered HTML means the server which sends the final result to the browser. You can view the rendered HTML from browser's Developer tools by pressing F11

Comment: @Rahil Wazir, thank you for clarifying..and basically putting it into simple enough terms for me to understand :) I tried the F11 key as you suggested in my Chrome, and it did not work. Are you simply referring to using page source to view rendered html?

Comment: @Jessica Yes the view source

Answer (score 0):

In the php code i dont see where you close the "a" tag, just follow the structure bellow. I hope it will work.

CSS:

```
#logo {
    width: 344px;
    height: 82px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    /*float: left;*/
    background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat;
}
h1.logo {
    width:344px;
    height:82px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
h1.logo a {
    display: block;
    height: 82px;
    text-indent: -3000em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="logo"><h1 class="logo" title="logo"><a title="logo" href="/">Logo</a></h1></div>
```

[Demo here..](http://jsfiddle.net/nyitsol/e26x5rcL/3/)

Comment: Thank you NYitsol for the great information, and this Demo site, jsfiddle is truly helpful. I was able to adjust the html and css to view my logo as a h1. However, my logo is only showing half of it. I tried adjusting the widths to see if this would help, but it did not. I am missing something pertinent. Would you mind checking it out please or anyone else? [link]http://jsfiddle.net/e26x5rcL/9/. I tried adding the html and css here, but it was too long.

Comment: Your logo is width: 270px; height: 112px; so you need to put that for the #logo here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/nyitsol/e26x5rcL/10/

Comment: Yes that did take care of the width issue, thank you :) However, I tried using the css and html from the snippets from the demo above, and it did not work on the site as planned. I think the site likes the css, but there may be something that needs to be adjusted in the code for the header. The home page only displayed its background color. It basically went blank. Though, it was perfectly fine in jsfiddle. I am not sure what else can be done, and have tried tinkering with the html with no improvements.

Comment: right click on the logo and inspect element in chrome and see what other css is interfering on that container. if you give me the live url, can give you the exact fix.

Comment: Yes, I would definitely like your help, thank you. My url without any periods is http:// ..r..e..n..t..a..l..o..g..y.(dot).n..e..t I tried as you suggested to use inspect element on the containers & took a look at the css. I am still learning, but the only thing I saw odd (using my non-professional eyes) was "em" was used at the end of text indent instead of px under h1.logo a {. I changed it to px to see if that made a difference, and no success. I had also tried changing the widths of the containers to a larger size to test it to see if that would resolve my blank homepage, and no luck.